# Python create a sub dictionary from a complex dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python as:

```
{4: [1, 2, 3], 12: [10, 11]}
```

I am trying to convert it into the below format:

```
{ 4: 1, 4: 2 , 4: 3, 12: 10 , 12:11}
```

I am able to do this using a loop but thats so inefficient. I was wondering if there is an easy way for this.. any idea anyone? thanks in advance.

Comment: That is actually a invalid structure in python, also can you add what you have tried for it, Were you trying to say `{ (4, 1), (4, 2) , (4, 3), (12, 10) , (12, 11)}` instead?

Comment: `{ (4: 1)` - this is invalid notation, correct your code

Comment: Devesh kumar, Thanks I have corrected the same.

Comment: @SarahB, the expected result is still invalid - you can't have such

Comment: @SarahB  you can edit your Question and correct the data type you want to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested)

```
_set = {} 
for key in dict:
     for value in dict[key]:
         _set.add((key, value))
```

Comment: he already said he did that with for loop and he is searching for a better way

Comment: Sorry didn't see, but there are no alternatives, because you are going to need to iterate over all your elements anyway

Comment: the answer above gave an alternative with list Comprehensions. it's pythonic and more readable

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you need a `list` of `tuple`

```
sum([[(x , z) for z in y ]for x ,y in d.items()],[])
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (12, 10), (12, 11)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to store in that format

{4: { 1 : 4 , 2 : 4 , 3: 4 }, 12 : { 10 : 12, 11: 12 } }

and  for sub_dictionary { 1 : 4 , 2 : 4 , 3: 4 } try to get 'keys' from 'values' that is 4

```
my_key = 4
for key, value in sub_dictionary.items():
    if value == my_key:
        print(key)
```

Comment: Dinesh, I like your idea.. will try this and provide the code.. thanks